# Join 3 tables on Rails

Tags: join, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have 3 tables :

- *playlists*   has_many :tracks
- *tracks*    belongs_to :playlist, has_many :answers
- *answers*    belongs_to :track

a *Playlist* has a theme (not unique, several playlists may have the same theme)
an *Answer* has a status : true or false

I want to query true answers for a given theme.

theoretically, this should work :

```
Track.joins(:answers).where(answers:{status:true}).joins(:playlist).where(playlists:{theme: myGivenTheme})
```

Actually, it works including .joins(:playlist), but fails whenever I add the where(playlists:...) condition.
I already tried Track.includes(:playlist), to try to fit the belongs_to, but failed too, with the following error message :

```
Track.joins(:answers).where(answers:{status:true}).joins(:playlist).where(playlist:{name:'French'}).count
 (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tracks" INNER JOIN "answers" ON "answers"."track_id" = "tracks"."id" INNER JOIN "playlists" ON "playlists"."id" = "tracks"."playlist_id" WHERE "answers"."status" = $1 AND "playlist"."name" = $2  [["status", true], ["name", "French"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "playlist"
LINE 1: ..."."playlist_id" WHERE "answers"."status" = $1 AND "playlist"...
                                                             ^
from /Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "playlist"
LINE 1: ..."."playlist_id" WHERE "answers"."status" = $1 AND "playlist"...
                                                             ^

from /Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
```

Comment: Fails how? Is there an error message or is there a result set which doesn’t match your expectations?

Comment: I'm adding the error message right now on the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem, hope this may help for I didn't find many docs about this specific syntax topic. The right query, to find the whole user's right answers (**answer.status = true**), for a given playlist theme, named **myGivenTheme** and a given **user**, is :

```
Playlist.where(theme: myGivenTheme).joins(tracks: :answers).where(answers:{status: true, user_id: self.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you raw sql

```
Track.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM tracks t
JOIN answers a ON a.id = t.answer_id
JOIN playlist p ON p.id = t.playlist_id
WHERE status = true
AND theme = ?', myGivenTheme);
```

This assuming you're using the convention for the columns

You can select the specific columns, the columns that doesn't exist on the track model will be added as part of it

You can also join the two tables at once

```
Tracks.joins(:answers, :playlists)
```

And I'm noticing you're using singular to join :playlist and plural :playlists for the where

Comment: seems that my joint attempts work with singular ```:playlist```, whereas plural is expected for ```playlists:{theme: 'myGicenTheme'}```.

Comment: I adapted this way : ```Track.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM tracks t JOIN answers a ON a.id = t.answer_id JOIN playlist p ON p.id = t.playlist_id WHERE status = true AND theme = ?', 'French');``` He's returning **NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for "French":String**, which is weird . The same if I do ``a.status```and ```p.theme```

Comment: Track.joins(answers: :playlists) was one of first attempts, but returned ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Answer' to association named 'playlists'; perhaps you misspelled it? from /Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:192:in `find_reflection'